# Java algorithm to check to detect if all characters in string are unique not working with Hashmap? Is there a better solution using map operators?

Tags: java

I have the following code for detecting if all the characters in a string are unique, return true if unique or false if not. Why do the characters in my map never increment beyond 1?

```
public static boolean hasUniqueChars(String word) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if(map.get(word.charAt(i)) == null) { // this appears to always equal null even though there is data after the first instance of a character is put into it?
            map.put(""+word.charAt(i), 1);
        } else {
            map.put(""+word.charAt(i), (Integer)map.get(""+word.charAt(i))+1);
        }
    }
    Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        if((Integer)pair.getValue() != 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;

}
```

Also is there a more "reactive" way to do this like maybe using map operators for each of the chars to help determine whether there is a duplicate character?

Comment: It would make more sense to use a `Map<Character, Integer>`.

Comment: Why don't you just use a Set? `if(charSet.size() < word.length())` then characters aren't all unique. you can do `word.chars().boxed().collect(toSet())` to get the set since you oinly care about the size.

Comment: You don't need to iterate over all characters. Once you find that Map already contains current character, you can immediately return true.

Comment: you also could use a Set<String> and add each char if it is not contained in it yet. if it is contained though, return false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
public static boolean hasUniqueChars(String word) {
    return word.chars().distinct().count() == word.length();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at your `for` loop:

```
for (int i=0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    if (map.get(word.charAt(i)) == null) {
        map.put("" + word.charAt(i), 1);
    } else {
        map.put("" + word.charAt(i), (Integer)map.get("" + word.charAt(i)) + 1);
    }
}
```

You are checking using `word.charAt(i)` instead of the concatenated string `"" + word.charAt(i)`.  Try using consistent keys everywhere and your problem might go away:

```
if (map.get("" + word.charAt(i)) == null) {
    map.put("" + word.charAt(i), 1);
} else {
    map.put("" + word.charAt(i), (Integer)map.get("" + word.charAt(i)) + 1);
}
```

Here is a demo showing that after making this change your code works as expected:

## Rextester

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not the best solution but don't forget about Set<> and fast iteration:

```
public boolean hasUniqueChars(String word) {
    Set<Character> characters = new HashSet<>();
    for(Character c : word.toCharArray()) {
        if(characters.contains(c)) return false;
        characters.add(c);
    }
    return true;
}
```